# phonegap push plugin- How do I change source="pgb" to npm

Tags: cordova, plugins, npm, push

I built an app with push messaging
I got the message plugin is not available anymore.

"This app uses plugins from the PhoneGap Build repository. These plugins won't be accessible after Nov 15th, 2016"

config.xml for pushplugin:

<    gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" spec="2.5.0" source="pgb" />

This is my code:

```
                    try {
                        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform == 'amazon-fireos') {
                            pushNotification.register(pushsuccessHandler, pusherrorHandler, {
                                "senderID": "123456789",
                                "ecb": "onNotification"
                            });
                        } else {
                            pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, pusherrorHandler, { "badge": "true", "sound": "true", "alert": "true", "ecb": "onNotificationAPN" });
                        }
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
                        txt += "Error: " + err.message + "\n\n";
                        console.log(txt);
                    }
```

// handle GCM notifications for Android
        function onNotification(e) {
            switch (e.event) {

```
            case 'registered':
                alert(e.regid);
                if (e.regid.length > 0) {
                    alert(e.regid);
                    var jsonText = {
                        userName: empId.value,
                        RegId: e.regid,
                        IsAndroid: 1,
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: basePath + "ExternalWebService.asmx/SaveRegId",
                        data: JSON.stringify(jsonText),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("secccess saveRegId");
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText + " " + xhr.error);
                            alert("error saveRegId");
                        }
                    });

                }
                break;
            case 'message':

                var snd = new Media("./audio/sound.mp3");
                snd.play();
                if (e.foreground) {//when the application is in the foreground (we can see it)
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                else {  // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                    if (e.coldstart) {//when the application is closed
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                    else {//when the application is open but in the background (we can’t see it)
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 'error':
                console.log('ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '');
                break;
            default:
                console.log('Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is');
                break;
        }

    }
    // handle callback notifications
    function pushsuccessHandler(result) {
        alert('pushNotification register success:' + result + '');
    }

    function pusherrorHandler(error) {
        alert('pushNotification register error:' + error + '');
    }
    function tokenHandler(result) {
        console.log('token: ' + result + '');
        var jsonText = {
            userName: empId.value,
            RegId: result,
            IsAndroid: 0,
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: basePath + "ExternalWebService.asmx/SaveRegId",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonText),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("secccess saveRegId");
            },
        });
    }
```

Comment: Searching for the same thing bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this
`< gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" spec="2.5.0" source="pgb" />`

And you have to end up with this:

`<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" />`

How can you do it?

First of all go to https://www.npmjs.com/ and search for the id of the plugin, in this case `com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin`.
If you find it, keep using the same id

In this case the plugin is not on npmjs because it's deprecated, so go to google and search for `com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin`

First link points to the [old deprecated repo](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).
The plugin's README.md will point you to the [new version of the plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)
On the Plugin's install information there is an [additional resources section](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PHONEGAP_BUILD.md#additional-resources) 
That explains how to use the plugin on phonegap build

`<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm">
    <param name="SENDER_ID" value="<Your Sender ID>" />
</plugin>`

If you want to specify a version you can do it using the spec attribute as before, this is what you have to add to use latest version on the moment of speaking

`<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.8.3" source="npm">
    <param name="SENDER_ID" value="<Your Sender ID>" />
</plugin>`

If you want to continue using your current plugin despite being deprecated you can use the github url instead of using npm

`<plugin spec="https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin" />`

Answer (score 0):

Okay the plugins exist in the NPM repository, but you'll just have to search for them. They have a different ID (package ID). Here is the Cordova Plugin search page:  http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/

I'm not sure which one you're using, but here are a few:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-pushplugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/PushPlugin_V2

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-gcmpushplugin

Here is the blog post from Phonegap saying that the PGP repository is shutting down in mid-November:

http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/10/13/pgb-repository-shutting-down/